# Add column in MySQL with number of total columns as title

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add a new column in the table named "tische" with the column-title of the total columns in this table?
I tried following codem but that doesn't work...

```
<?php

//Creating an sql query  
$number = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tische'";
$rs     = mysqli_query($number);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
$add    = "ALTER TABLE tische ADD COLUMN `$result` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER zeit";

//Importing our db connection script
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Executing query to database
if (mysqli_query($con, $add)) {
    echo 'Element erfolgreich hinzugefügt';
} else {
    echo 'Fehler!';
}
//Closing the database 
mysqli_close($con);
```

When I execute the querys in the console of phpMyadmin, it works. But not in this php-script... Please help me

Comment: `$rs = mysqli_query($number);` pass connection to it and magic may happen. `$rs = mysqli_query($con, $number);`

Comment: ...waiting for an *"Oh wow, it works!!!"* ;-)

Comment: If I replace the line `$rs...` i get the error-message! -> No magic :(

Comment: I did say "may", not "will". So check for errors on the query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I.e.: `else {
        echo 'Fehler!' . mysqli_error($con);
      }`

Comment: Lord, `require_once('dbConnect.php');` put that on top first under the opening php tag, besides of what I said up there. That should work now but still check for errors on the query, assuming you are successfully connected using the mysqli_ API.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Now it creates a new column! BUT its title is "Array" and not the number of the total columns

Comment: welcome. check in phpmyadmin, there's a php code generator under "Create PHP code", try that. TBH, I've never ran code like yours before; interesting though.

Comment: That, and/or try an alias `SELECT COUNT(*) as title`, but am not 100% sure about that; it's worth a try.

Comment: What is the idea behind that column? Other than a strange way of keeping some kind of history, I couldn't come up with a reason, so I'm curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `require_once('dbConnect.php');` in page of top. Add `$con` variable in `mysqli_query` first param like `$rs = mysqli_query($con, $number);`

SYNTAX of mysqli_query :

`mysqli_query(mysqli $con , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ])`

Your correction code is bellow :

```
<?php   
    //Importing our db connection script
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Creating an sql query  
    $number = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tische'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con, $number);

    $column_name = 0;
    if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $column_name = $result['total'];
        }

        $add = "ALTER TABLE tische ADD COLUMN `$column_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER zeit"; 

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$add)){ 
        echo 'Element erfolgreich hinzugefügt';
        } else {
        echo 'Fehler!';
        }
    }
    //Closing the database 
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! You helped me a lot!